# Resizing partitions in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, gparted

Because of a mistake during the instalation, I've got my Ubuntu partition with only 80GB, and my Windows 10 partition (I have a dual boot) with 180GB. My disk has 500GB.

I sucefully resized my Windows partition by moving the "Microsoft Reserved" partition to the left and next resizing the main partition.

But I can't do the same with Ubuntu, because GParted don't allows me to do it, and I can only reduce the partition. I can't neither move nor increase the Ubuntu partition. I have already tried to use the insalation media and using Gparted on another live USB (I've used Fedora). It didn't worked.

Right now, this is my partition table:

[image: Gparted partition table]

Note that there is a key symbol on the Ubuntu partition. ¿What does it mean?

The Resize/move menu shows this:

[image: Gparted resize menu]

There is no way to increase the partition, and I can't move it.

Comment: Your partition *sda5* is mounted, thus you cannot re-size (thus the lock symbol in `gparted`) until after it's unmounted. The easiest (by far) way to achieve a re-size is to boot a 'live' system (such as Ubuntu install media) where it won't be *in-use* and re-size can easily be performed.

Comment: I agree with @guiverc. Why can't you resize using live USB. Can you put a screen shot?

Comment: Okay, it workded!

Comment: I guess that it was because I were using Gnome Disks instead of Gparted on the Live session (in order to avoid connecting to Internet and upgrading). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in you current system because you cannot unmount the root partition so you should have a live cd.
After booting to live cd unmount the root partition you want to extend. As the free space is above your root partation you have to move the partition so the data loss may occur so I strongly recommand to backup the data that are important.
After doing backup open Gparted and that right click the partition you want to extend and select `resize/move`. set `free space preceding` to 0 and add add the free partition size to `new size`(in your calculate around 185*1024+74*1024 MiB). and keep the `free space following` to the initial value. Now this process will take a quit long time so wait to get the new partition size.